# How can I make sure my seedlings don't die in summer?

Tags: seedlings, temperature

I did a bad thing: I planted several punnets of seedlings in mid-summer.

It's been 5 days and many look like they're already dead. They are (or were) a small daisy-like ground cover. It's been hot this last week, as high as 36C (97F).

What can I do to make sure they survive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prick them out into individual cells, then, when they're big enough, move into pots. Once they've grown to a good size, with a good root system, then you can plant them out- but even then, they will need plenty of water to establish themselves.

Depending on what you're growing, some seeds can be sown or scattered on the ground directly in spring, where they can be left to grow or not grow, when they see fit, depending on the prevailing conditions (temperature, moisture, friability of soil).